# python throws NoneType error when trying to write to yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

My code is relatively simple but I know the file searching works, however, writing the data to a YAML refuses to work right. I have gone through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645391/how-to-append-data-to-yaml-file) for advice and have tried extend(), append(), and update(). All to no avail, any suggestions would be a help.

```
import os
import YAML

drives = ["A:\\", "B:\\", "C:\\", "D:\\", "E:\\", 
          "F:\\", "G:\\", "H:\\", "I:\\", "J:\\", "L:\\"]

for drive in drives:
    print("Searching in drive: " + f"'{drive}'")
    dir_path = drive
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for file in files:

            # change the extension from '.mp3' to
            # the one of your choice.
            if file.endswith('.exe'):
                back = '\\'
                print("File path: " + f"'{root + back + str(file)}'")
                program = file
                path = root + back + str(file)

                with open('programs.yaml', 'r') as yaml_file:
                    cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
                    info = program + ": " + path
                    print("YAML data: " + f"'{info}'")
                    cur_yaml.append(info)
                    print("curyaml:" + cur_yaml)
                if cur_yaml:
                    with open('programs.yaml', 'w') as yaml_file:
                        yaml.safe_dump(cur_yaml, yaml_file)
```

The goal is to have it search all drives in a computer and log the location of the executable files in a YAML for later use, the intent is for login things like steam, individual games, programs, and the like.

The error I keep getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\HELIX\Modules\Program Finder\search\search.py", line 24, in <module>
    cur_yaml.append(info)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
Searching in drive: 'A:\'
Searching in drive: 'B:\'
Searching in drive: 'C:\'
File path: 'C:\actions-runner\bin\Runner.Listener.exe'
YAML data: 'Runner.Listener.exe: C:\actions-runner\bin\Runner.Listener.exe'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The last thing I can point out is that my YAML file is empty, I have yet to decide how to structure the data for this section of a larger program I am making.

Comment: ``yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)`` provides a ``None`` value because that is what the YAML contains. If you want to append to its data, the YAML must contain a list.

Comment: well that  help thank you very much,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

type of `cur_yaml` is `str()`

split by underlying character .

[image: flow]

`'''The last thing I can point out is that my YAML file is empty, I have yet to decide how to structure the data for this section of a larger program I am making.'''` in this case `NoneType` object are loaded.

[image: empty inside]

Comment: "type of cur_yaml is str()" Can you please clarify what you mean by that? The error message seems to clearly show it's of type ``NoneType``.

Comment: update. empty source file .